# how to get json url with add variable url link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, getjson

how do I get the JSON URL with variable for the parameter, please help me, I'm new to learning programming

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var username=$("#nama_member1").val();
var url = "http://localhost/gps/json.php?username=";
$.getJSON(url+username, function(result) {}
```

Comment: not clear what you are asking , you are already sending the request to the url with the username appended

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks almost good. The question is if you have a folder on your localhost which provides a file called json.php and your localhost is a running Server with PHP. If so your json.php could look like:

```
<?php

    // json.php

    // Check if Parameter exists
    if (isset($_GET['username'])) {

        // Query to Database
        $json = $result['from']['database'];

    }

    // return Json
    echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

or much more easier

```
<?php

    // json.php

    // check param and return it
    if (isset($_GET['username']) {

        $json['username'] = $_GET['username'];

    } else {

        $json = 'Param Username not found';

    }

    // return Json
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

You can put this file in your folder gps and would call it like you did already.

```
http://localhost/gps/json.php?username=
```

Not sure if this answers your question fully. If not, provide more info on the expected result or describe it in more detail.